# Device Notification or value change, find it in other device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, nsnotificationcenter, cfnetwork

I'm developing some application which should notify my current device values into other devices within certain area. Let say i'm having app, the same app installed in other 3 devices. When i change something in my device, that should be notified in other device. Like, i'm selecting one button, that button selection should be on other 3 devices too.

Is it possible to do without web service and is there any specific frameworks there in iOS to do this task. Its kind of bluetooth searching devices within the area. It should be within the room, without any internet or wifi something.

Can anyone help me to find the solution.

Thanks,