# Detect iPhone device which using same wifi

Tags: iphone, ios, network-programming, wifi

how can i detect other iPhone devices in my wifi. After i found other iPhone devices, I want to send some values to them from my App. If i find 3 devices , i send any values that should go to all the three devices. In which way, i can achieve this.

Can anyone help me to find this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve it by detecting whether the SSID is the same, with the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library) . Also, you can double confirm by checking their IP. They suppose to be in subnet.

Comment: I tried that link, but i'm getting only SSID of my wifi. But how can i know other 3 devices also using the same wifi

Comment: install the same apps in all devices.

Comment: but, i want, if i changed some values in my app. that should be known by other app which is installed in other devices. how could i do this one. it'll be helpful for me, if u give answer for this.

Comment: sounds like you want to probe devices without modifying other devices. You can't.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this, because i have already asked my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907981/device-notification-or-value-change-find-it-in-other-device). This is what i want. I can use web service, but it might take time to update things in other device. I just want to get the values of other app, as soon as it changed. Can you suggest me way to achieve this

Comment: Can't. Existing apps with similar features require all apps installed the same App.